# Add dynamic form fields using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/qL83cf2v/1/`1`

I have tried above jsfiddle example in my project. I got syntax error due to (...)invoke many places especially in handleChange function.

Example: 
`users[i] = {...users[i], [name]: value}`

I thought react version problem, so i have changed react older version(0.14.3) in that case also i got error. Now am using react version(^16.4.2).

Why i got this syntax error? and how to resolve this issue? Anyone have idea share with me? All suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What version of babel are you using? Depending on the version, you might need [babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread.html)

Comment: yeah because your spread syntax looks fine

Comment: am using babel version (^6.26.0) @Sung Kim

Comment: @SungKim I have installed babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread.Once again i got that same error.
  
               Without user[i] i didn't get error.
  handleChange(i, e) {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
    let users = [...this.state.users];
    users[i] = {[name]: value};
    console.log(users);
    this.setState({ users });
  }
   
  With user[i] i got error.
  handleChange(i, e) {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
    let users = [...this.state.users];
    users[i] = {...users[1],[name]: value};
    console.log(users);
    this.setState({ users });
  }

Comment: Is it possible to share the full source on GitHub/GitLab?  Without all the configuration options it's hard to see what's causing the error

Comment: There is no option to share on GitHub/GitLab due to company legal policy,anyway thanks for u r response @SungKim